# How to ignore a specific field when updating db entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a class MessageModel, which has a field
 `public string? AttachedFile`

My controller adds a message to the database

```
[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Create Message")]        
public async Task<IActionResult> AddMessage(MessageModel messageModel)
{
    if (messageModel.AttachedFile != null)
    {
        var mediaDto = _mapper.Map<MediaDto>(messageModel);
        var createdMedia = await _mediaService.Create(mediaDto);

        messageModel.SetMediaGuid(createdMedia);
    }
    return Ok(await _messageService.Create(_mapper.Map<MessageDto>(messageModel)));
}
```

My other controller edits the message, but i don't want to update AttachedFile field when editing my existing message

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Edit Message")]

public async Task<IActionResult> EditMessage(MessageModel messageModel)
{
    await _messageService.Update(messageModel.Id, _mapper.Map<MessageDto>(messageModel));
    return Ok();
}
```

How do i ignore AttachedFile field when using Edit Message Controller

Comment: What do you mean by ignore?

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic if i change the value in swagger for my AttachedFile when editing a message, the entity updates, but i want to save AttachedFile as it was when i created a message

Comment: Please add code for what is happening inside messageService.update

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic
`public async Task Update(Guid id, MessageDto MessageDto)
{
    var entity = _mapper.Map<MessageDto, Message>(MessageDto);
    entity.Id = id;
    
    _messageRepository.Update(entity);
    
    await _messageRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the easiest option would be to just use 2 separate models (possibly with some base one to contain base/shared props):

```
public abstract class MessageModelBase
{
   // ...
}

public class AddMessageModel : MessageModelBase
{
   public ... AttachedFile {get; set;}
}

public class EditMessageModel : MessageModelBase
{
}
```

And use them:

```
[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Create Message")]        
public async Task<IActionResult> AddMessage(AddMessageModel messageModel)
{
    // ...
} 

[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Edit Message")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditMessage(EditMessageModel messageModel)
{
    // ...
}
```

Also possibly `EditMessage` should be PUT, not POST.

Answer (score 1):

Either you go with the answer provided above from Guru, or you make an adjustment in your repository method `messageRepository.Update(entity)`, which will only update the fields you want to update.

Something like this, given you're using entity framework.

```
   public void UpdateEntity(MessageModel message)
    {
        // Retrieve the existing entity
        var existingEntity = _dbContext.GetEntityById(message.id);

        if (existingEntity != null)
        {
            // Modify only the fields you want to update
            existingEntity.SomeField = newFieldData;

            // Save changes to the database
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        // Handle the case where the entity is not found
    }
```